# Добавить набор свойств к элементу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, dom

Когда создается объект jquery, в него можно добавить различные свойства через объект, будь то текст, атрибут или стили:

```
$('<h1>', {
    text: '...',
    class: 'heading'
});
```

Но возможно ли добавить такой же набор свойств уже созданному элементу? То есть, конечно, есть отдельные функции типа attr или addClass, но мне нужен универсальный метод для всех таких свойств. Что-то типа такого:

```
$('h1').addProperties({
    text: 'New text',
    id: '30'
});
```

Или, возможно, имеются какие-либо плагины для решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я написал свою реализацию. По крайней мере, этого хватает для нужных мне свойств.

```
for (var key in attributes) {
    if ($.fn[key]) {
        element[key](attributes[key]);
    }

    else {
        element.attr(key, attributes[key]);
    }
}
```

Вся суть в том, что при создании нового элемента в jquery названия большинства свойств такие же, как и названия соответствующих функций для редактирования этих свойств. Т.е.:

```
$('<h1>', {
    text: '...'
});
// То же самое, что и
$('<h1>').text('...');
```

Поэтому я просто проверяю, существует ли такая функция в jquery, и выполняю на элементе. Если же ее нет, я присваиваю элементу атрибут. Здесь "attributes" - объект, содержащий свойства, "element" - соответственно элемент, на который все это применяется.

Answer (score 2):

То что Вы ищете это [`$(selector).attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) и [`$(selector).text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$('h1').attr({
    id: 'id30'
})
.text('New text');

console.log(id30)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: И у меня добавится атрибут "text". А мне нужно, чтобы текст добавился в элемент.

Comment: @IkorJefocur а как мы должны были это понять из вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), при создании jQuery элемента можно использовать объект, элементы которого используются как имена атрибутов и их значения. Пример этого Вы продемонстрировали в своём вопросе.
Если Вам необходимо перезаписать множество атрибутов элемента, то согласно [документации](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs) сделать это можно так:

```js
$('selector').attr({
    text: 'New text',
    id: '30'
});
```

> При установки атрибута `class` или при использовании атрибута `type` элементов `input` и `button` в браузере IE8 и старее, будет выбрасываться исключение, если имена атрибутов указаны без кавычек.

---

Если же Вам нужно просто сохранить дополнительныю информацию в элемент, то для этого можно использовать:

#### Mетод jQuery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
$( "body" ).data( "bar", { isManual: true } );
$( "body" ).data( { baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } );
$( "body" ).data( "foo" ); // 52
$( "body" ).data(); // { foo: 52, bar: { isManual: true }, baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

#### HTML5 [data-* атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Позволяют хранить дополнительную информацию в стандартных элементах HTML, без хаков вроде нестандартных атрибутов, лишних DOM-свойств или Node.setUserData().

Пример использования:

```html
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

Доступ в JavaScript

```js
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Comment: Мне не нужны манипуляции с data-атрибутами. Мне нужно добавить объект, в котором значение text - текст внутри элемнта, css - объект со стилями и т.д.. Ну и атрибуты в т.ч..

Comment: @IkorJefocur data-атрибуты добавлены как альтернатива. Если Вам нужно "привязать" некий объект к DOM-элементу, то используйте метод jQuery .data().

Comment: У меня следующая ситуация: Есть функция, которая клонирует определенный элемент, и присваевает ему объект со значениями, указываемый в аргументах. И нужно через эту функцию иметь возможность присвоить текст, стили, значения полей и т.д.. Мне кажется, что data тут не поможет.

Comment: @IkorJefocur если у Вас есть дополнительная информация, либо уточнения, то добавляйте их в вопрос.

Comment: @IkorJefocur мне кажется, что я наконец-то понял, что Вы имели ввиду... Обновил ответ.

Comment: Это мне уже объяснили. Дело в том, что при создании элемента кроме атрибутов можно задать, к примеру, тот же текст, являющийся именно текстом, а не атрибутом с именем "text". Т.е. jquery как бы сам понимает, что это текст, а не атрибут. При использовании attr у меня добавляется как раз атрибут "text".

Comment: @IkorJefocur а в чём причина, т.е. необходимость непосредственно такого подхода? Вопрос теперь понятен, но цель - нет. В любом случае Вы можете использовать `text()` или `value()` с последующим вызовом `attr()`.